# How to calculate X with: percent of X = Y

Tags: linear-algebra, percentages

I am sorry if this is impossible to compute in one equatation.

I am trying to compute the following:
for example

```
y = 574  
x - ((16% of x) + y) = 0
```

the goal is to find out what is x so as to make it equal to 0.

I have managed to reach the number but only using a loop in a programming function,
lets say x starts at 1111,  so in that loop i did -1 until it reached the desired 0.

I was wondering how to organize the equatation to find out x in one go.

basically, is it possible to find out x here:

```
0 = x - ((16% of x) + 574)
```

if so, please advice how?

I tried to search in google but I had no clue how this kind of math is defined.

Thank you

edit of what I tried so far:

I already know by my other calculations that:

```
 x = 683
```

for example:

```
0 = x - ((16% of x) + 574)
0 = 683 - ((109.28) + 574 )
0 = 683 - 683.28
```

but I calculated this programmatically,  the question is how to reach this using an equitation.

Comment: Do you mean $\%$ as the percentage or the modulus/remainder?

Comment: Hi, I mean percentage,   aka  16% of 100 = 16 .    and I have tried to convert 16% of 100 to 0.16 but it doesn't give me the right results, I will add an example in a moment

Comment: I got $2050/3$ or $683.\bar3$ for this $x$ by using $0.16$.

Comment: What is the official answer?  I think you  should get $x-(.16x+574)=0\implies .84x=574\implies x=\frac {574}{.84}=683.\overline 3$.

Comment: I think this is the answer, I got it,  if you want please post an answer and I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: In short, if you take $x=683$ there will be a roundoff error. (this time, of $0.28$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a value of $y$, you want to solve the following for $x$:
$$x - (0.16x + y) = 0$$
But that's easy:
$$x - (0.16x + y) = 0$$
$$x - 0.16x - y = 0$$
$$(1 - 0.16)x - y= 0$$
$$0.84 x-y = 0$$
$$0.84 x = y$$
$$x = \dfrac{y}{0.84}$$
In the specific case $y=574$:
$$x = \dfrac{574}{0.84}\approx 683.3333$$
Check:
$$x - (0.16x + y) = 683.3333 - (0.16(683.3333) + 574) \approx 0$$
The result is only approximately zero here (and not exactly zero) because we rounded the value for $x$. The actual value is $683\frac13$, which has an infinitely repeating decimal representation $683.\bar{3}$ .